# DNN upgrade version 7 skin failure

Tags: dotnetnuke, upgrade

I have upgraded a site to DNN 7.2.1 following the recommended path from 5.6.8

If I stay in the skin MinimalExtropy, all seems fine.

If I change even to the Gravity skin, much goes wrong:

- using "settings" on a page shows the settings dialog, but no changes are made on "update"
- it is impossible to change out of the new skin without renaming the skin folders on the site, forcing a return to MinimalExtropy.

It appears that some part of the support for skins has disappeared.

Any suggestions of how to rescue the site?

Thanks
JC

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are getting a Javascript error on the page and that is causing the postbacks in DNN to not fire properly. I would start by looking at your javascript console in your browser and trying to track down the source of JS errors.

Also be sure to check the Skin settings in the ADMIN/SITE SETTINGS page.

You might try a skin specifically setup for DNN7, I have one called HammerFlex, you can find more info about that skin at http://www.christoc.com/Projects/HammerFlex